# Adicionando itens/subitens em massa no ListView

Tags: delphi

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando adicionar itens em massa em um ListView.

Preciso colocar o texto de um Memo separado por ponto e vírgulas (;) como itens e subitens nesse ListView.

Exemplo:

> Texto digitado no Memo:
>   João da Silva;Curitiba - PR
>   Maria Oliveira;São Paulo - SP
>   Roberto Silva
>   Pedro Miranda;Porto Alegre - RS

Na 1a coluna do ListView ficarão os nomes.
Na 2a coluna as cidades (algumas vezes a cidade não será mencionada).

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Parece algo simples, porém ao pesquisar na internet só encontrei exemplos muito complicados.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    Var Item: TListItem;
        Conta, Posicao : Integer;
    begin

      // pega o memo e adiciona no listview
      ListView1.Items.Clear;

      for Conta := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
      begin
        Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
        Posicao := Pos('-', Memo1.Lines[Conta]);

        if (Posicao = 0) then
          Item.Caption := Memo1.Lines[Conta]
        else
        begin
          Item.Caption := Copy(Memo1.Lines[Conta],0,Posicao-1);
          Item.SubItems.Add(Copy(Memo1.Lines[Conta],Posicao+1, Length(Memo1.Lines[Conta])));
        end;
      end;
    end;

    procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var
      Col : TListColumn;
    begin
      ListView1.ViewStyle := TViewStyle.vsReport;

      // Criando titulo das colunas
      Col := ListView1.Columns.Add;
      Col.Caption := 'Cidade';
      Col.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
      Col.Width := 200;

      Col := ListView1.Columns.Add;
      Col.Caption := 'Estado';
      Col.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
      Col.Width := 100;
      // Fim criando titulos das colunas

      // Preenchendo o memo
      Memo1.Lines.Clear;
      Memo1.Lines.Add('João da Silva;Curitiba - PR');
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Maria Oliveira;São Paulo - SP');
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Roberto Silva');
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Pedro Miranda;Porto Alegre - RS');
      // Fim Preenchendo o memo
    end;
```

Comment: Funcionou 100%. Muito obrigado.